# Does Angular's DestroyAfterEach option affect the speed of Jest tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular12

[DestroyAfterEach](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/ModuleTeardownOptions) is a new option that was added in Angular 12.1, and promises to greatly speed up test performance ([details here](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2021/06/25/what-is-new-angular-12.1/)). However, when making this change, I am not noticing any speed difference. I suspect this may be because I'm using Jest, which does not involve a browser.

Is it expected that Jest does not have any speed improvements when applying this option? It's also possible I'm applying the option incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed change the speed. Have just checked it on our project (Angular 13.3.2, Karma 6.3.9, Jasmine-core 3.10.1). To compile and finish the tests it takes 45 seconds from the moment of running `npm run test` command with `destroyAfterEach: true` and 67 seconds with `destroyAfterEach: false`.

`SUMMARY: √ 1154 tests completed i 3 tests skipped TOTAL: 1154 SUCCESS`